# Implementing orchard's IMembershipService with existing ASP.NET Identity provider

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, orchardcms

I already have a membership provider implemented with `ASP.NET Identity`. I decided to use Orchard cms. I want to use Orchard `FormsAuthentication` with my implementation of a provider that currently works with `OAuth`.

I tried to implement `IMembershipService` and use `ASP.NET Identity`. But I don't know exactly how to implement it. For example there is a `GetUser` method that returns `IUser` containing a `ContentItem` which is not clear to me how to populate it with my data.

```
[OrchardSuppressDependency("Orchard.Users.Services.MembershipService")]
public class MyMembershipService : IMembershipService {
    //...

    public IUser GetUser(string username) {

        var user = new MyUserPart() {

            //From my DB and ASP.NET Identity
            Id = -1,
            Email = string.Empty,
            UserName = string.Empty,

            //How to populate this?
            ContentItem = new ContentItem() { }
        };

        return user;
    }
}
```

*Here is what I want to do (I want to use MyMembershipService instead of Orchard's).*

[image: Implementing orchard's IMembershipService with existing ASP.NET Identity provider]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `ContentItem` by using the `IContentManager` interface, something like:

```
IContentManager lContentManager = ...;
ContentItem lContentItem = lContentManager.Create("User");
lContentItem.As<UserPart>.UserName = ...;
```

But keep in mind that a user is bound to the `UserPartRecords` DB table, thus you could get into trouble if another module tries to modify / change and save the user to DB (as there would be no data row then).